# why am I getting this error in windows powershell?

Tags: powershell, shell, error-handling, filenotfoundexception, computer-forensics

I was trying these power forensics command from this website the 1st two commands worked perfectly while the next 3 commands gave errors, I am sharing one of the error below. Please tell me the solution to get rid of this error.

Command - PS C:> Get-ForensicFileRecord -Path C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe

Error:
Get-ForensicFileRecord : Path C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe not found.
At line:1 char:1

- Get-ForensicFileRecord -Path C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ForensicFileRecord], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception,PowerForensics.Cmdlets.GetFileRecordCommand
  ```

The link  which I followed for this tutorial:
[PowerForensics - PowerShell Digital Forensics | Get-ForensicFileRecord](https://powerforensics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modulehelp/Get-ForensicFileRecord/)

Comment: I'll be honest, the example you've posted, should not, on a modern Windows system, return that message. Modern Windows default to using `C:` as the system drive, and `cmd.exe` is always located in the system drive under `\Windows\System32`. As a test however, you could try using `$Env:SystemDrive` instead of `C:`, and update your question with the output, if that still fails.

Comment: Which website would that be? Was there a tutorial to be followed? Maybe the toolkit used needs extra settings, but that is hard to say without knowing the tool source.

Comment: I have updated the post with the link through which I was using that command, please check.